# Atomic Formulas in Second Order Logic

Tags: logic, higher-order-logic, second-order-logic

I'm studying second-order logic and I would like to know if the phrase about atomic formulas in Figure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rj4KA.png) is correct. If addition, I would like to know what means a second-order predicate like $P^n_k$ or $R_nk$ like in the Figure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rj4KA.png).

Thanks!!

[image: Atomic Formulas in SOL]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is correct. In [SOL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-order_logic) we have second-order *predicates*, i.e. predicates having pradicates as arguments.

They express [properties of properties](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/properties/#FirOrdVsHigOrdPro):

> *redness* is a property that is instantiated by apples;
>
> *being a color* is a property that applies to redness.

In FOL we have *individual* variables, that we may quantify, and *predicate* symbols, that we interpret.

Thus, we may have the formula : $\forall x P(x)$ that reads "every object is $P$", whose meaning (truth value) will depend on the interpretation (how the predicate symbol $P$ is interpreted).

In FOL, in addition to the above, we have *predicate* variables, that we may quantify, and *second-order predicate* symbols, that we interpret.

Thus, we may have the formula : $\forall X \mathcal R(X)$ that reds "every (first-order) property is $\mathcal R$", whose meaning (truth value) will depend on the interpretation (how the second-order predicate symbol $\mathcal R$ is interpreted).

And we may have also $\forall X \forall x X(x)$, that reads "every object has every property".

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Now it's make more sense for me about the phrase cited. So, $P^n_k$ is a predicate variable with n-arity (receives n arguments that can be individuals or predicate symbols) and k is useful to enumerate predicate variables (example $P^n_1$, $P^n_2$, k=2)? But these predicates have something in common or can be two predicate totally diferent from each other?

Comment: @MatheusPrandini - yes, they are like the *individual* variables $x_1,x_2,\ldots$. The "exponent" $n$ says that they have $n$ argument places. Tehy are different symbols but they must be interpreted according to the interpretation...not necessarily with different meaning. Consider e.g $(x \le y)$ and interpret it in $\mathbb N$: the formula is satisfied by $0$ as value for both $x$ and $y$, because $0 \le 0$.

Comment: Okay, I understand now about their interpretation. But considering the predicate variables $P^2_1$ and $P^2_2$. Can I say that $P^2_1$ receives two arguments ($X1$ and $X2$) and means that the first one is greater than the second one. Similarly, $P^2_2$ receives two arguments too, but means that the first one is lesser than the second one. Without looking to the interpration of them, is this correct? So, they are atomic formulas? Thanks again!

Comment: @MatheusPrandini - you cannot say what they mean without an interpretation $P(x,y)$ can mean $x < y$ in one int and $x > y$ in a different one. The meaning of *predicate* symbols are defined by the interpretation.

Comment: But this is the same for FOL and SOL; you have to review the basic definition of syntax and semantics, starting from the simpler case of FOL.

Comment: Okay I see your point. Means is highly associated with the interpretation, you're correct! I think i would like to say "defines" rather than "means", because I'm looking just for the syntax of the predicates without taking semantics in account, did you understand better now?